Blend mode Doesn't change
I was making a scene and everything was going fine until I imported a character (shrek body) and I just couldn't change the opacity of it . So I set the transparent value from light paths from render to 0 to fix this problem . But when I imported another model every model's blender mode is now set to Alpha Hashed/Alpha Blend. and I can't change them to Opaque/Alpha clip . when I try to change it I click and nothing happen. Even when I create a simple cube , I still can't change its blend mode
